# In a bash script, git does not recognize it own directory?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, bitbucket-server

So I have written a bash script within Atlassian-Stash for post-receive events. In this script, after a commit has been made, it creates a codecollaborator code review. To create a code review, it needs commit title, commit user and git SHA for any changes and uploading the changes to the code review. To get these informations, I clone'd the directory to --depth=1 (even without --depth=1) and work with git log (options).

The problem I am seeing is that if I run the script manually, it works just fine. However, if it runs after a commit has been made, it errors out after it clones the directory saying it is not a git directory. If I cd into the directory after the script exits, I am able to run git log (and other git commands).

Things I tried to troubleshoot are 
1. Permissions issues (running it as root), so I am not seeing any permissions issues.
2. troubleshooting it with bash -xv and until that point everything looks good.
3. I also put it status checks with $? 
4. I tried to move .git to git-backup, wait 3 seconds and moved it back, still the same issue. 
5. I ran ls -ltra to make sure that it has all the files and .git directory.

Now, I am out of options. Has anyone ran into this kind of problem before?

Anyone know where I might be doing something wrong or missing something?

I tried to be as descriptive as possible, if the question does not make sense or need a sample script, please let me know.

Adding the script and its error output below.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

CCollabExe='/usr/local/bin/ccollab'
CCollabUrl='--url http://***:8080'
CCollabUser='--user ******'
CCollabPassword='--password ******'
CCollabConnection="${CCollabExe} ${CCollabUrl} ${CCollabUser} ${CCollabPassword}"
CCollabStuff='/home/stash/repositories/tmp'
CloneDir="${CCollabStuff}/ClonnedDir"
StashUser='******'
StashPass='******'
RepoURLlinkGit="http://${StashUser}:${StashPass}@******:7990/scm/t/test1.git"

unset SSH_ASKPASS

# Test function to check if a varibale is empty
CheckIfVarEmpty () {
  local Variable="$1"
  if [[ -z ${Variable} ]] ; then
     echo "Variable $1 '\${Variable}' is empty, exiting"
     echo "Lets try to go back in the git dir" && cd ${CloneDir} && git log -10
     cd /root && cd ${CloneDir}
     [[ -d .git ]] && cp -rp .git git-backup && rm -rf .git && echo "sleeping 3" && sleep 3 && mv git-backup .git
     git log -10
     exit 0
  fi
}

#Create a new CCollab temp dir, clone the directory and get commit title, user and SHA info
   rm -rf ${CCollabStuff} && mkdir ${CCollabStuff} && cd ${CCollabStuff}
   git clone ${RepoURLlinkGit} ${CloneDir}
   cd ${CloneDir}
```

***# below is where its erroring out.***

```
   CommitTitle=$(git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1)
   CheckIfVarEmpty ${CommitTitle}
   CommitUser=$(git log  --pretty=format:"%an" -1)
   CheckIfVarEmpty ${CommitUser}
   CommitSHA=$(git log  --pretty=format:"%h" -2)
   CheckIfVarEmpty ${CommitSHA}
   CommitSHA1=$(echo $CommitSHA | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }')
   CommitSHA2=$(echo $CommitSHA | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }')
   echo "=========="
```

Error out is:

```
remote:   rm -rf ${CCollabStuff} && mkdir ${CCollabStuff} && cd ${CCollabStuff}
remote: + rm -rf /home/stash/repositories/tmp
remote: + mkdir /home/stash/repositories/tmp
remote: + cd /home/stash/repositories/tmp
remote:   git clone ${RepoURLlinkGit} ${CloneDir}
remote: + git clone http://******:******@******:7990/scm/t/test1.git /home/stash/repositories/tmp/ClonnedDir
remote: Cloning into '/home/stash/repositories/tmp/ClonnedDir'...
remote:   cd ${CloneDir}
remote: + cd /home/stash/repositories/tmp/ClonnedDir
remote:   CommitTitle=$(git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1)
remote: git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1
remote: ++ git log --pretty=format:%s -1
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Comment: Yes please, a copy of the script would be a start.

Comment: tripleee, I have added the snippet of the code that is erroring out.

Comment: Please replace line
`CommitTitle=$(git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1)`
with
`CommitTitle=$(pwd>&2;git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1)`
and show as a result.

Comment: Here it is.


remote: + cd /home/stash/repositories/tmp/ClonnedDir
remote:    CommitTitle=$(pwd; ls -altr ; git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1)
remote: pwd; ls -altr ; git log  --pretty=format:"%s" -1
remote: ++ pwd
remote: ++ ls -altr
remote: ++ git log --pretty=format:%s -1
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: + CommitTitle='/home/stash/repositories/tmp/ClonnedDir
remote: total 52
remote: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 19 10:56 ..
remote: drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Nov 19 10:56 .git
remote: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10 Nov 19 10:56 file9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know nothing about Atlassian but it's clear from the error output that you're tripping over one of the hook traps I noted in an answer I can't find now:

- In a git hook, the environment variable `GIT_DIR` is set (to `.` in `--bare` repos, to `.git` in non-bare ones).  This is valid only until you `cd` to some other directory, often in a sub-process run from the hook script that has no idea that `$GIT_DIR` is pointing off to some now-inappropriate place.

(The `git clone` step works because it is not looking for a git directory, it's just creating a new one.)

The quick and easy fix is `unset GIT_DIR`.

Comment: Thanks torek. I had no idea about that, neither would I have imagined to look at (possibly an issue with) git. "unset GIT_DIR" did the trick and moved on to the next error. 

Thanks very much for saving the day